# My "Press Enter to continue" function asks for input at the wrong time

Tags: c++, cin

I'm working on a small text adventure game with some classmates, and I decided to add a pause() function to main, so that big walls of text (represented with "story text") could be broken up a bit, for easier reading. The code sort of looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
    
void pause()
{
   cout<<"Press Enter to continue." << endl;
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

int main()
{
    int input=1;
    
    cout << "Story Text" << endl;
    pause();
    cout << "Story Text 2, make a choice, 1 or 2" << endl;
    cin >> input;//if you comment this out it works like intended???
    switch(input)
    {
      case 1 :
        cout << "Story Text choice 1" << endl;
        break;
      case 2 :
        cout << "Story Text choice 2" << endl;
        break;
    }
    pause();
    cout << "Story Text Final" << endl;
}
```

Normally it will output "press enter to continue" and then wait for the user to hit enter, and then continue the program. It works fine at first, but if I try using it after some other things happen in main, it starts acting weirdly. It's supposed to look like this:

```
Story Text
Press Enter to continue.

Story Text 2, make a choice, 1 or 2
1
Story Text choice 1
Press Enter to continue.

Story Text Final

Process returned 0 (0x0)
```

But it ends up looking like this:

```
Story Text
Press Enter to continue.

Story Text 2, make a choice, 1 or 2
1
Story Text choice 1
Press Enter to continue.
Story Text Final

Process returned 0 (0x0)
```

The last part is like, swapped in order, so the text doesn't get broken up really, the "Press enter to continue" text just gets sandwiched between the two bigger bits of text, and the user hits enter at a point where it's not useful. It doesn't always do the second behavior, sometimes it works correctly, but I can't figure out what's causing the incorrect behavior. I can show more of my code if needed.

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Prefer to always have a `default` case in your `switch` statement.  It will help tremendously when tracking down root causes.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you, I have addressed this.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> input;
```

If you type `1` and hit enter this will generate two keystrokes:

```
1<ENTER>
```

The `>>` operator ***only reads `1`***. The newline remains unread. That's how the `>>` operator works. It reads only the input it extracts, namely the value `1` here, and *nothing more*. The `<ENTER>`, newline, remains unread.

You can pretty much figure out everything else what happens. Your code calls `pause()` a 2nd time. At this point **The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming** becomes in force. The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming states: "your computer will do exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do". You told your computer to discard everything until a newline is read, in `pause()`, so pause will read from standard input, see the remaining, unread newline, and immediately return.